# How to filter OpenCV error messages in Java

Tags: java, opencv

The issue of this question has already been discussed e.g. for

- [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567808/how-to-suppress-opencv-error-message/17575610#17575610)
- [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602465/how-to-stop-opencv-error-message-from-printing-in-python/49604578#49604578)

[The OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#ga8cd28eccccb695570cdaf86a572d2c0c) describes

```
ErrorCallback cv::redirectError     (   ErrorCallback   errCallback,
        void *      userdata = 0,
        void **     prevUserdata = 0 
    )
```

**How can this be made to use to e.g. filter out annoying messages?**

An example is

```
[mjpeg @ 0x7fe5a696ea00] unable to decode APP fields: Invalid data found when processing input
```

from a Logitech USB Webcam mjpeg stream which is created on every single frame and is superflous and not needed.

There is also a [loglevel](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.9/da/db0/namespacecv_1_1utils_1_1logging.html) available. Unfortunately the import org.opencv.utils only contains "Converters" but no logging as of OpenCV 3.4.8

**How could the loglevel be set from Java?**

```
enum    LogLevel {
  LOG_LEVEL_SILENT = 0,
  LOG_LEVEL_FATAL = 1,
  LOG_LEVEL_ERROR = 2,
  LOG_LEVEL_WARNING = 3,
  LOG_LEVEL_INFO = 4,
  LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG = 5,
  LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE = 6
}
```

**Would [Redirect System.out and System.err to slf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187461/redirect-system-out-and-system-err-to-slf4j) help?**

Comment: IIRC, the message you provide as an example is not from OpenCV, it's from ffmpeg, which just writes it to standard error stream.

Comment: @DanMašek thx it would see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35215447/1497139 points in the right direction then. But how can this be achieved in the OpenCV scenario where ffmpeg is embedded as a library?

Comment: see https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/12780

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How can this be made to use to e.g. filter out annoying messages?**
**How could the loglevel be set from Java?**

At this time (2020-01) it can't. Even if the API would be accessible from Java the bug https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/12780 would prevent it.

**Would [Redirect System.out and System.err to slf4j][5] help?**

No - see [Junit test case](https://github.com/rc-dukes/dukes/blob/master/rc-roi/src/test/java/org/rcdukes/roi/TestROI.java) below. The result is:

```
11:05:56.407 [main] DEBUG u.o.l.s.c.SysOutOverSLF4JInitialiser - Your logging framework class ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger should not need access to the standard println methods on the console, so you should not need to register a logging system package.
11:05:56.417 [main] INFO  u.o.l.s.context.SysOutOverSLF4J - Replaced standard System.out and System.err PrintStreams with SLF4JPrintStreams
11:05:56.420 [main] INFO  u.o.l.s.context.SysOutOverSLF4J - Redirected System.out and System.err to SLF4J for this context
11:05:56.421 [main] ERROR org.rcdukes.roi.TestROI - testing stderr via slf4j
[mjpeg @ 0x7f958b1b0400] unable to decode APP fields: Invalid data found when processing input
[mjpeg @ 0x7f958b027a00] unable to decode APP fields: Invalid data found when processing input
```

where the decode APP field part is still showing up via some stderr magic.

```
  @Test
  public void testLogStderr() throws Exception {
    NativeLibrary.logStdErr();
    System.err.println("testing stderr via slf4j");
    NativeLibrary.load();
    VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture();
    // Dorf Appenzell
    //String url="http://213.193.89.202/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi";
    // Logitech Cam on test car
    // url="http://picarford:8080/?action=stream";
    File imgRoot = new File(testPath);
    File testStream=new File(imgRoot,"logitech_test_stream.mjpg");
    assertTrue(testStream.canRead());
    capture.open(testStream.getPath());
    Mat image=new Mat();
    capture.read(image);
    assertEquals(640,image.width());
    assertEquals(480,image.height());
    capture.release();
  }
```

**Funny side fact**

According to the [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) documentation 
*Log coloring can be disabled setting the environment variable AV_LOG_FORCE_NOCOLOR or NO_COLOR, or can be forced setting the environment variable AV_LOG_FORCE_COLOR. The use of the environment variable NO_COLOR is deprecated and will be dropped in a future FFmpeg version*

But there seems to be no option to change the Logging level from an environment variable ...