# ffmpeg --help, node child_process spawn trigger stderr

Tags: node.js, typescript, ffmpeg, child-process

So I simply run `ffmpeg --help` using node.js, why is there `stderr`? I think it should be only `stdout`. Is it an issue of ffmpeg or node.js?

Code:

```
import path from 'path';
import {spawn} from 'child_process';

const childProcess = spawn(path.join(__dirname, 'ffmpeg'), ['--help']);
childProcess.stderr.setEncoding('utf-8');
childProcess.stderr.on('data', data => {
  console.log('stderr:');
  console.log(data);
});
```

Output:

```
stderr:
ffmpeg version 4.4-tessus  https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay

stderr:
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
```

Comment: OK, It may be ffmpeg's by design behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169650/differentiate-between-error-and-standard-terminal-log-with-ffmpeg-nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer my own question: ffmpeg by default redirects normal output to stderr. It is strange but it is how it is designed